# Sort list in List' s classes

Tags: c#, list, sorting, methods

I searched how to sort list in list' s classes. On my `atractions[i].profit` I valuse of profits and I want to sort that list. Below I present my code and attempt to resolv it.

```
class AtractionPoint
{
    public double coordinateX { set; get; }
    public double coordinateY { set; get; }
    public double stylePoints { set; get; }
    public List<int> distances = new List<int>();
    public List<double> profit = new List<double>();
    public List<double> neighbour = new List<double>();

    public AtractionPoint(double x, double y, double s)
    {
        coordinateX = x;
        coordinateY = y;
        stylePoints = s;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < atractionsCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < atractionsCount; j++)
    {
         if (i == j) 
             atractions[i].profit.Add(0);
         else
             atractions[i].profit.Add(atractions[i].stylePoints / atractions[i].distances[j]);
    }
    atractions[i].profit.OrderBy(d => atractions[i].profit);
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to perform sorting on your own or you can use .NET structs to resolve it? I guess what I am asking whether this is homework?

Comment: No. It is not homework. I read about sort with using Compare<T> but I don t know how to use it there. Sorting or my own, you mean using loops?

Comment: Just use SortedList, it supports sorting for primitive types out of the box.

Comment: Oh it is very intresting. I didn' t know about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But that is only the case if you have unique values.

Comment: So it is wrong :(

Comment: try this it return you list of sourted atractions[i].profit.OrderBy(d => d).ToList();

Comment: Result is that same

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to sort `atractions[i].profit` for each `i`? Then just call `atractions[i].profit.Sort()`

Comment: But I want to change distance and neighbour also